# Ionic How to handle signout correctly(empty navstack and push loginpage)

Tags: ionic-framework

I am writing signout method for my app.The thing is i want to empty nav stack before signing out but i dont know how ??

```
signout(){
    //unsubscribtionshere
    this.app.auth().signOut().then(a =>{
        //clear navigation stack
        alert("you successfully signed out");
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage); //push user to loginpage
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are doing with `this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);` There is no navigating back after that.

But if you want to manually reset the navigation stack then you can use [setPages](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#setPages):

```
this.navCtrl.setPages([{
    page: HomePage
}]);
```

Comment: Do you know how to remove existing tabs segment after seting root to loginpage ?